# Breadcrumb with Backbone.Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to implement breadcrumb using `Marionette.CollectionView` and `Marionette.ItemView`. I want to add breadcrumbs to the list from any part of the module.

Here is the module which I wrote:

```
App.module("BreadcrumbModule", function(BreadcrumbModule){
var instance;

var Breadcrumb = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        link        : '',
        name        : ''            
    } 
});

BreadcrumbModule.BreadcrumbList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Breadcrumb
});

var BreadcrumbView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName : 'li',

    render : function() {
        var liData = '';
        if(this.model.get('link') == '#') {
            liData = 'You are here: ';
        } else {
            liData = '<a href="#' + this.model.get('link') + '" class="tabSection">' + this.model.get('name') + '</a>';
        }

        $(this.el).html(liData);
        return this;
    }
});

BreadcrumbModule.BreadcrumbListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    id: "Breadcrumb",                

    itemView: BreadcrumbView,        

    initialize : function() {                       
        this.collection = new BreadcrumbModule.BreadcrumbList();                   

        this.collection.bind('add', this.appendBreadcrumb);       

        //this.collection.add({link: '#', name: 'You are here : '});
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.appendBreadcrumb);   
    },

    addBradcrumb: function(breadcrumbList){

        breadcrumbList.forEach(function(breadcrumb) {
            //console.log(breadcrumb);
            this.collection.add(breadcrumb);
        }, this);
    },      

    appendBreadcrumb: function(breadcrumb) {
        var breadcrumbView = new BreadcrumbView({
            model : breadcrumb
        });            

        $(this.el).append(breadcrumbView.render().el);
    }
});

// Singleton
BreadcrumbModule.getInstance = function() {
    if(!BreadcrumbModule.instance) {
        instance = new BreadcrumbModule.BreadcrumbListView();
    } 

    return instance;        
}        

});
```

My plan to access this module as follows:

```
 //var breadcrumbs = []; 
 //breadcrumbs.push({link: 'book', name: 'Book'});

 //var breadcrumbListView = App.BreadcrumbModule.getInstance();

 var breadcrumb = new App.BreadcrumbModule.Breadcrumb({link: '#', name: 'You are here: '});
 var breadcrumbList = new App.BreadcrumbModule.BreadcrumbList();  
        breadcrumbList.add(breadcrumb);
 breadcrumbListView.addBradcrumb(breadcrumbs);
```

I can see the default one is showing("You are here:") and the 'collection' is growing when I add new breadcrumbs but its not reflecting in the view.

What could be the reason?

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

//San.

Comment: Any reason you are using an extra array (`breadcrumbs`) that you then pass on to a method on the CollectionView instead of just adding a new model to the collection itself? Your CollectionView should just `listenTo` the collection changing and re-render.

Comment: I'm new to Backbone. I don't have any specific reason to add the extra array, may be I understand the things wrongly. I just tried what you mentioned here, but didn't work, may be I have to do some more modifications. Am I following the correct coding structure? Do you have any working sample for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a simple example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zaSvT/
The main differences to your code are these:

The `CollectionView` is listening to its collection and re-renders every time the collection changes (e.g.

```
var BreadcrumbListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        el         : '#breadcrumbs',
        childView  : BreadcrumbItemView,
        initialize : function(){
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render );
            this.render();
        }
    });
```

And here I just instantiate it with a new collection (1 dummy item to start with):

```
var breadcrumbCollection = new Backbone.Collection([{ name : 'foo', url : 'foo' }]);

var breadcrumbView = new BreadcrumbListView({
    collection : breadcrumbCollection
});
```

When I add a new item to the collection it will automatically appear:

```
breadcrumbCollection.add({ name : 'foo', url : 'bar' });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to analyze your approach and understand my mistakes.

Comment: I have a question: If I want to load the template('#link_template') from a template file *without* RequireJS, what modification I have to do?

Comment: When I moved this code to a module(BreadcrumbModule), it shows an error message "Error: A "childView" must be specified"

Comment: Can you maybe provide your code somewhere? JSFiddle?

Comment: JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Saneesh/cbYEL/5/   This is the code I wrote for Template file. I cannot assign values to the ids in the template from the view. In my template file if there is a DIV tag with id 'rate_select_template', I cannot access it in the View class using $('#rate_select_template') but if I add the DIV tag before the backbone.js it works.

Comment: That sounds quite tricky, it's pretty much what RequireJS would be there for. You would probably need to only start your module once the AJAX call returns (in `success`) and not earlier.

Comment: How can we achieve it? module load after AJAX success?

Comment: There is a `startWithParent` attribute on modules (http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.module.html#starting-sub-modules-with-parent), have a look at that maybe. Only start the module once the template is loaded?

Comment: I think all the AJAX calls will happen at the beginning. In the firebug we can see all the templates are loaded before the rest of the parts, this may be handled by jQuery. Where the template file content loads when we call $.get() of jQuery ? I think its not available in the DOM that's why we cannot access the DIV ids using $('#testid') in the Views.